# Memoria dinámica en C introducir cadena de texto

Tags: c, imprimir

Estoy intentando que el siguiente programa me almacene mediante memoria dinámica y luego me muestre los diferentes elementos introducidos por teclado.
El problema es que mediante %s no funciona y mediante %c solo muestra el primer carácter de la cadena de texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cliente{
    char dni;
    char nombre;
    char apellido;
}cliente_t;

cliente_t* crear_cliente(){

    cliente_t* nuevo_cliente = malloc(sizeof(cliente_t));
    if(!nuevo_cliente)printf("Error");

    //asignamos los valores
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el dni:\t");
    scanf("%s", &nuevo_cliente->dni);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el nombre:\t");
    scanf("%s", &nuevo_cliente->nombre);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el apellido:\t");
    scanf("%s", &nuevo_cliente->apellido);

    return nuevo_cliente;

}


void imprimir_cliente(cliente_t* cliente_impreso){
    printf("DNI: %s\n Nombre: %s\n Apellido: %s\n", cliente_impreso->dni, cliente_impreso->nombre, cliente_impreso->apellido);


}

int main()
{
    cliente_t* cliente1 = crear_cliente();
    imprimir_cliente(cliente1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te sale algún error o algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrás que declarar los campos dni, nombre y apellido como vectores de char con el tamaño máximo que quieras permitir:

```
#define TAM_MAX 80
typedef struct cliente{
    char dni[TAM_MAX];
    char nombre[TAM_MAX];
    char apellido[TAM_MAX];
} cliente_t;
```

Y luego cuando vayas a hacer el scanf:

```
scanf("%79s", &nuevo_cliente->dni);
```

Answer (score 5):

Has declarado los campos dni, nombre y apellido como tipo char, por lo que solo hay espacio para un caracter.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Que sean de tipo array de caracteres, como se te sugiere en otra respuesta. El problema es que no sabes qué tamaño es el apropiado, y de hecho, si pones algo como `char nombre[20]`, estarás reservando 20 bytes para cada nombre. Si ocupa menos desperdicias memoria, si ocupa más no cabe.
- Que sean un puntero a char y que se reserve memoria para el número de letras necesarias, según la longitud del nombre.

Este segundo caso parece mejor, pero aún no está claro cómo funcionaría. Si no sabemos de antemano qué nombre va a introducir el usuario ¿cómo podríamos saber cuánta memoria reservar?

El truco en este caso sería tener un array de longitud suficiente (podemos ponerlo muy grande por si acaso, por ejemplo 200) y usar ese buffer como almacén temporal para leer la respuesta del usuario. Esa respuesta ocupará menos de 200 bytes, digamos que ocupa 8. Los restantes de momento se están desperdiciando pero no importa demasiado porque lo que haremos a continuación será usar `strdup()` para sacar un duplicado de la respuesta. Ese duplicado usará ya sólo la memoria mínima necesaria (8), pues copiará sólo caracteres del buffer hasta encontrar el terminador de cadena, en lugar de copiar los 200.

`strdup()` te retorna un puntero a la copia. Puedes asignar ese puntero a uno de los campos de tu estructura, y repetir la jugada (reusando el mismo buffer) para ir leyendo cada campo.

Otra cosa, en lugar de `scanf("%s")` puede interesarte usar `fgets()`, pues `%s` sólo leerá letras hasta el primer espacio (lo que te causará problemas en nombres compuestos, pues sólo leerá el primero), mientras que `fgets()` lee hasta el retorno de carro (inclusive). Además a `fgets()` le puedes indicar un máximo de caracteres a leer, y asegurarte así de que no te sales del espacio reservado en tu buffer.

El siguiente código implementa esta idea:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct cliente{
    char *dni;
    char *nombre;
    char *apellido;
}cliente_t;

cliente_t* crear_cliente(){

    char buffer[200];

    cliente_t* nuevo_cliente = malloc(sizeof(cliente_t));
    if(!nuevo_cliente)printf("Error");

    //asignamos los valores
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el dni:\t");
    fgets(buffer, 199, stdin);
    nuevo_cliente->dni = strdup(buffer);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el nombre:\t");
    fgets(buffer, 199, stdin);
    nuevo_cliente->nombre = strdup(buffer);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el apellido:\t");
    fgets(buffer, 199, stdin);
    nuevo_cliente->apellido = strdup(buffer);

    return nuevo_cliente;

}


void imprimir_cliente(cliente_t* cliente_impreso){
    printf("DNI: %s\n Nombre: %s\n Apellido: %s\n", cliente_impreso->dni, cliente_impreso->nombre, cliente_impreso->apellido);


}

int main()
{
    cliente_t* cliente1 = crear_cliente();
    imprimir_cliente(cliente1);
    return 0;
}
```

Detalles (que deberías corregir):

- La memoria nunca es liberada. Los punteros retornados por `strdup()` deben ser liberados con `free()` cuando ya no sean necesarios.
- Las respuestas del usuario, al ser leidas con `fgets()` contienen al final un retorno de carro que probablemente no quieras. Puedes eliminarlo sobreescribiéndolo con un byte de valor 0 antes de llamar a `strdup()`. Ya que 0 es el terminador de cadena, esto evitaría que `strdup()` lo copie.

Comment: Mira ese `fflush(stdin)` papá'! Jajaja, muy buena respuesta :D

Comment: @NaCl Sí. Ese `fflush(stdin)` ya estaba en la pregunta y se me pasó señalar que básicamente [no sirve para nada](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html). No está definido qué ha de hacer un `fflush()` sobre un buffer de entrada, y menos sobre la entrada estándar.